# Ignore Certain GPS Satellites Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, android-location

I'm developing an app which uses GPS to determine where the user is.

I have a GpsStatusListener which retrieves the Pseudo Random Number (PRN) from the locked satellites. I want to be able to ignore certain satellites based on their PRN. I'm sure I've seen something in the documentation which does this but I can't find it! Can anyone help?

Thanks